# Normal convergence of $\sum_{n \geq 0}\mathrm{cos}(x)\, (\mathrm{sin}(x))^{n+\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

Consider the following series of functions

$$\sum_{n \geq 0}\mathrm{cos}(x)\, (\mathrm{sin}(x))^{n+\sqrt{n}}$$

It converges absolutely in all $[0,2\pi]$. But where does it converge normally?

On textbook I find that it converges normally only in intervals $[a,b] \subset [0,2\pi]$ that do not contain $\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\frac{3}{2} \pi$, and there it holds that

$$|\mathrm{cos}(x)\, (\mathrm{sin}(x))^{n+\sqrt{n}}|<\delta^n \,\,\,,\,\, \delta <1 \tag{1}$$
and therefore the series is normally convergent.

But in my view $(1)$ is also valid in **all** $[0,2\pi]$, since in $\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\frac{3}{2} \pi$ the function is simply $0$.

So can I conclude the normal convergence in all $[0,2\pi]$, or is it incorrect to do so?

Comment: @user251257 fixed

Comment: Can I know what's your textbook?

Comment: @user296113 There is no english version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that normal convergence of a series $\sum f_n$ of functions on a set $S$ means

$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \lVert f_n\rVert_S < +\infty,$$

where $\lVert f\rVert_S := \sup \{ \lvert f(x)\rvert : x \in S\}$.

If we look at intervals $[a,b] \subset [0,2\pi]$ that contain neither $\frac{\pi}{2}$ nor $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, then there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $[a,b]$ doesn't intersect $\bigl(\frac{\pi}{2} - \varepsilon, \frac{\pi}{2} + \varepsilon\bigr)$ or $\bigl(\frac{3\pi}{2} - \varepsilon, \frac{3\pi}{2} + \varepsilon\bigr)$. Thus the behaviour of the $f_n$ in some small neighbourhood of these points plays no role when we investigate pointwise, uniform, or normal convergence on $[a,b]$. But if say $\frac{\pi}{2} \in [a,b]$, then, unless we have the degenerate interval $\bigl[\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\bigr]$, the behaviour of $\cos x \cdot \lvert \sin x\rvert^{n + \sqrt{n}}$ in small neighbourhoods of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ does play a role. And the behaviour on $\bigl(\frac{\pi}{2} - \varepsilon, \frac{\pi}{2}\bigr)$ or $\bigl(\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} + \varepsilon\bigr)$ is not so nice that we have normal convergence (though it's nice enough for uniform convergence).

Consider, for $a > 0$, the function $f_a \colon x \mapsto \cos x \cdot (\sin x)^a$ on $\bigl[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr]$ (we restrict to an interval on which $\sin$ is strictly positive to avoid the absolute value). We know that $f_a$ vanishes at the end points of the interval, and it is strictly positive on the interior. Let's find out where $f_a$ attains its maximum, and how large it becomes. Differentiating yields

$$f_a'(x) = a(\sin x)^{a-1}(\cos x)^2 - (\sin x)^{a+1},$$

and thus the only critical point of $f_a$ is at $\arctan \sqrt{a}$. On the interval $\bigl[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr)$, we have the identities

$$\cos \varphi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2 \varphi}}\qquad\text{and}\qquad \sin \varphi = \frac{\tan \varphi}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2 \varphi}},$$

so we find

$$f_a(\arctan \sqrt{a}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a}} \biggl(\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{1+a}}\biggr)^a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a}}\biggl( 1 + \frac{1}{a}\biggr)^{-a/2}.$$

For large $a$, the second factor is very close to $e^{-1/2}$, and thus

$$\lVert f_a\rVert_{[0,\pi/2]} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+a)e}}.$$

By the symmetries of $\sin$ and $\cos$, the behaviour on $\bigl(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\bigr]$ and near $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ is the same, so on a non-degenerate interval $[a,b]$ containing $\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, we have

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} < \lVert \cos x\lvert \sin x\rvert^{n+\sqrt{n}}\rVert_{[a,b]} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

for large enough $n$, and thus the functions don't decrease fast enough for normal convergence. The series converges uniformly on the whole interval $[0,2\pi]$ (or, by periodicity, on all of $\mathbb{R}$), but not normally.